# Linear regression through ellipse shows unexpected behavior

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am drawing a 2D ellipse on an empty image. Now, I want to fit a line through the ellipse to get the major axis. Knowing that there are plenty of options (PCA, image moments, etc), I was thinking that Linear Regression should do the job. However, it only "works" if the rotation of the ellipse is parallel to the x axis. Why is this? Shouldn't any symmetric point cloud that is spread equally give the midline?

This is the code I was using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from skimage.draw import ellipse
from ipywidgets import interact
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

@interact
def rotateAndFit(rot:(-90,90)=-90):
    im = np.zeros((300,300), dtype=np.float64)
    im[ellipse(im.shape[0]//2, # center x
               im.shape[1]//2-10, # center y
               120,            # radius major axis
               40,             # radius minor axis
               im.shape,       # image shape
               rot/180*np.pi)] = 1  # rotation angle in degree,


    # Get corresponding x and y values
    y, x = np.where(im)

    # Do Linear Regression
    lr = LinearRegression()
    lr.fit(x[None].T,y)

    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.plot([0, 300], [lr.intercept_, lr.coef_[0]*300+lr.intercept_])
    plt.axis([0,300,300,0])
    plt.title('rotation $r = {}°$'.format(rot))
```

The code provides the following output:

[image: Rotation of ellipse and corresponding linear fit]

I am really confused, any ideas? I was using ridge and lasso regression to adjust weights, but they lower the weights, but it seems that the weights, i.e. the slope has to be steeper, I think the linear regression underestimates the slope. Interestingly the linear regression is often kind of "point" symmetric, but not symmetric across the line... The behavior close to 0° I understand, the slope cannot be infinity. But it should at least work for a low degree of rotation.

Comment: I think that this is due to the fact that regression only minimzes in y. In very simple words, the amount of points is not always equal below and above (in y direction) the main axis. Orthogobal distance regression should give the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regession line cannot coincide with the main axis because regression minimizes in y-direction rather than perpendicular to the regression line. The following sample uses orthogonal distance regresison instead of linear regression in y and it gives the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from skimage.draw import ellipse
from ipywidgets import interact
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, Data

def lin(beta, x):
    a,b = beta
    return a*x+b

@interact(rot=(-90,90))
def rotateAndFit(rot=-90):
    im = np.zeros((300,300), dtype=np.float64)
    im[ellipse(im.shape[0]//2, # center x
               im.shape[1]//2-10, # center y
               120,            # radius major axis
               40,             # radius minor axis
               im.shape,       # image shape
               rot/180*np.pi)] = 1  # rotation angle in pi (40°),


    y, x = np.where(im)

    d = Data(x,y)
    m = Model(lin)
    o = ODR(d, m, [0,0])
    out = o.run()
    a,b = out.beta

    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.plot([0, 300], [b, a*300+b])
    plt.axis([0,300,300,0])
    plt.title('rotation $r = {}°$'.format(rot))
```

Comment: Is ODR line the same as 1st PCA component?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I think PCA is like the linear version of ODR.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the above answer, here's a schematic drawing of what you're doing by using an OLS with the points of an ellipse. Since you have two points at every x, you're essentially finding the mean of y at every x. For the un-rotated ellipse (top ellipse in the figure), this works as you expected. But when you rotate the ellipse (bottom ellpise), at a given x, the point halfway between the two points on the ellipse is well off the main axis of the ellipse. So yeah, you have to minimize orthogonal to the rotation axis.

[image: schematic result of an OLS regression for points of an ellipse]

Comment: thank you so much, that is really helpful! now it makes totally sense.